# Order of Operations Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, integer

I have a float variable `mynumber` in Django templates, and I need to round it to the nearest integer **without third party filters**, so I'm following this logic:

```
int(mynumber - 0.5) + 1
```

In Django templates I can do this:

```
{{ mynumber|add:"-0.5"|add:"1" }}
```

But the problem, as you can see, is that there is no order of operations, so I get a different number than the expected, how can I solve this? I haven't found a way of putting parenthesis, and also I need to convert to integer after the first operation.

Comment: Can't you simply use `{{ value|floatformat:0 }}`? this will round to zero decimal places, so to the integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem, as you can see, is that there is no order of operations.

The problem is that you never call `int` somewhere. The `add` template filter is [implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L659-L668):

> ```
> @register.filter(is_safe=False) def add(value, arg):
>     """Add the arg to the value."""
>     try:
>         return int(value) + int(arg)
>     except (ValueError, TypeError):
>         try:
>             return value + arg
>         except Exception:
>             return ''
> ```

So it will *first* cast `int` on *both* the value and the operand, and since `0.5` can not be converted to an `int`, it will return the empty string.

> and I need to round it to the nearest integer without third party filters.

The good news is, there is a built-in template filter to do exactly that: [**`|floatformat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat). As the documentation says:

> If used with a numeric integer argument, `floatformat` rounds a number to that many decimal places. (…) Particularly useful is passing 0 (zero) as the argument which will round the float to the nearest integer.

So you can render this with:

```
{{ mynumber|floatformat:"0" }}
```